# Does anyone have ideas about ping and pong frames?

Tags: java, websocket

I'm using websocket with JAVA EE 7,in the turorial,I meet the words "ping" and "ping",does any one kown the meaning and usefulness？

Comment: Could you send link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket001.htm,search the keyword "ping" or "pong"

Comment: From Wikipedia: [Ping/Pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)#Echo_request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a `ping` is a packet or message sent primarily to ensure the connection is still present and active. (I believe the term comes from sonar, the "ping" being the sound the sonar system makes so it can listen for echos.)

People sometimes use `pong` to refer to a reply to such a packet, probably because of the game of table tennis ("ping pong" in the U.S.).

Specifically in regard to web sockets, [the specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#ping-and-pong-frames) tells us this is exactly what ping and pong frames are: A means of ensuring that communication is still possible:

> **6. Ping and Pong Frames**
>
> The WebSocket protocol specification defines Ping and Pong frames that can be used for keep-alive, heart-beats, network status probing, latency instrumentation, and so forth. These are not currently exposed in the API.
>
> User agents may send ping and unsolicited pong frames as desired, for example in an attempt to maintain local network NAT mappings, to detect failed connections, or to display latency metrics to the user. User agents must not use pings or unsolicited pongs to aid the server; it is assumed that servers will solicit pongs whenever appropriate for the server's needs.

Comment: If you know it, what do you want to know, @MuRong?

Comment: I visited the wiki,look the ping and pong in detail